# filter certain results in google search

Tags: google-search

I want to get the query results that exclude certain results.

Here is an example:

Suppose I search *www.google.com*.

Then the results should be pages that are **not** from **.google.com* pages(or exclude pages from Google domain).

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll see some hits from foreign google domains, but this will get you pretty close:

```
www.google.com -site:google.com
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I perform the query? I add it as a parameter but nothing changed. Or is there any links they provide such functionality?

Comment: How's this: [https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=www.google.com+-site%3Agoogle.com](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=www.google.com+-site%3Agoogle.com)  or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh,this is not what I need. I  need pages that are **not** from google domain. By the way, any suggestion on improving my question?

Comment: I see, you want to exclude google.com.au, google.com.uk, etc. and not just google.com.  This seems to work: "www.google.com" -site:google.com -site:google.*  [link] https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ajwebnet.net+***#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22www.google.com%22+-site:google.com+-site%3Agoogle.*&pbx=1&oq=%22www.google.com%22+-site:google.com+-site%3Agoogle.*&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=54449l56680l8l56903l2l2l0l0l0l0l132l258l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=4b3ab7d42af55be3&biw=1624&bih=93

Comment: cool, thanks. May I ask where you get this kind of information. Like google search tricks. Another little question. What does the two `-site` mean?

Comment: I just learned the site:domain.com filter from someone a while back, but [here's a page with lots of info](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/?hl=en)  The "-site:" option is a negate operator "-" and a search result limit directive that only returns results for a specified domain.  I don't actually know why just specifying "-site:google.*" doesn't work, so I had to add "-site:google.com" in addition.